# How to access a web service with the following parameters and client proxy generated based on a wsdl

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soa

I have been provided with a WSDL and have generated the proxy class based on this WSDL. Sorry cannot provide the WSDL due to security concerns. The method in the proxy class that I'd like to call is:

```
    public HeaderValueType GetStatus(System.DateTime RequestorTrxTime, string RequestorContext, string MessageIdentifier, string ProfileNumber, string ProfileType, int RequestIndicator, out ResponseBodyType Response) {//Some code}
```

I am just wondering what the fields

```
string RequestorContext, string MessageIdentifier
```

Are meant to be because I have seen requestorContext being passed as an object like this:

```
OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext
```

But not as a string the same goes for MessageIdentifier.

I have not got access to the creators of this WSDL for a while and cant get access, so I thought if any one would have a clue.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "I have seen requestorContext being passed as an object like this..".. Where did you see that? Can you post code sample.

Comment: Here is a quick sample I could find right now. USE THIS [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) then look for the following code on the page: 'InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);

MyContractClient proxy = new MyContractClient(context);'

Comment: Sorry I meant it does not pass it directly to the service its calling but to a method in the client's own service proxy.

Comment: The code segment you refer to is used if you want to create a Duplex client proxy. In the case of Duplex WCF service, the proxy maintains a callback channel between client and server, that's why the client will use the `InstanceContext ` for the callback mechanism. Is your service a Duplex service? Maybe this is just a nomenclature confusion and the `string RequestorContext` parameter refers to something else completely than an `InstanceContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try calling the service just be passing some values into these fields? It looks more like naming coincidence. Check that linked XSDs from WSDL specify this as message content. Also check that WSDL contains policy assertion called `CompositeDuplex` and assertions for reliable messaging (it should be  called `RMAssertion`). It it doesn't it is not `WsDualHttpBinding` where `InstanceContext` is used to expose callback contract and those parameters are only data related - meaning of those parameters must be described by service provider.